# Asmack/Openfire 401 error

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, openfire, asmack

I'm trying to write a simple XMPP application on Android using asmack, but I've encountered a problem that I cannot login to several jabber servers. For example, I can't login into my test Openfire server, although the code works fine with jabber.org accounts.

Login code:

```
public void login() throws XMPPException
{
    if (connection != null && connection.isConnected())
    {
        try 
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            int resource_int = generator.nextInt();
            connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD, 
                             "Smack_" + Integer.toString(resource_int));
        } 
        catch (XMPPException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connection.disconnect();
            setConnection(null);
            throw e;
        }
        Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
    }
}
```

As I said, it works with jabber.org, but Openfire returns `not-authorized(401)` error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try removing your resource parameter at login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used Openfire, but I'm sure there is a Logfile somewhere - can you post it?

IIRC in Android some security functions (not sure if for SSL or TLS) are not compatible to Smack or Asmack, maybe thats the problem. In this case there is a way to solve it by using an own Socket connection (instead of the included SSL functions of Smack) - To verify this you can port your (XMPP-relevant) code to PC and use the Standard Smack Library.

Another point is, that there are different Smack ports for Android. I personally use the Asmack port from the Beem-project (because the originally Asmack had some issues - but I can't remember which ones...)

But still...without more information I can only guess.

Comment: His problem is that it works on one server but not the other.  Not likely an issue on the client side as it should fail in both cases.

Comment: Not necessarily...maybe the servers require different login mechanisms. In Asmack you can enable the debug mode (`ConnectionConfiguration.setDebuggerEnabled(bool)`) so you can trace the stanzas in LogCat, maybe there you can find a helpful difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the same account and password on the OpenFire server?  Try logging into your server using the same username and password with an existing XMPP client.  Take Android out of the equation altogether and make sure you can log into both servers first.